# React-native TexField with floating inline suffix

Tags: react-native

I'm building a text field component with inline floating suffix. Everything works fine on iOS. When I click in a placeholder, the suffix moves to the left. On Android, the placeholder is cleared, and the suffix stays where it was. I would like him to behave like iOS.

Link to Expo snack: https://snack.expo.io/@galechus/textfield-with-floating-inline-suffix